# How to resolve the 'WARN Sourcemap for 'plugin-vuetify:components' warning

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxt3, vuetifyjs3

I added the following section to `nuxt.config.ts`, referring to this page:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/

```
hooks: {
  'vite:extendConfig': (config) => {
    config.plugins!.push(
      vuetify({
        styles: {
          configFile: 'assets/main.scss',
        },
      })
    );
  },
},
```

However, I encountered several warnings like these:

"[9:09:38] WARN Sourcemap for 'plugin-vuetify:components/VMessages/VMessages.sass' points to missing source files."

"[9:09:45] WARN Sourcemap for 'plugin-vuetify:components/VSelectionControl/VSelectionControl.sass' points to missing source files."

"[9:09:46] WARN Sourcemap for 'plugin-vuetify:components/VResponsive/VResponsive.sass' points to missing source files."

"[9:09:46] WARN Sourcemap for 'plugin-vuetify:components/VProgressLinear/VProgressLinear.sass' points to missing source files."

Furthermore, I'm currently unable to display the page.

I'm not sure how to resolve these errors, so I would appreciate it if anyone could provide some advice.

The entire code for the application in this repository:

https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site/tree/feature/override-sass-variables

The warning has been reported as a GitHub issue
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/issues/290